How to show the laplace trasnform of a translated piecewise function
I'm learning laplace transforms, and righ now I'm on their properties.
I am given the following problem:

I've done the obvious of ∫ f(t-c) exp(-st)ds but I get stuck at this point on how to integrate. What is to be done next?

Hint: the function is zero on some interval, so you can begin integrating from where?

@SeanRoberson, yeah with a function of zero at 0<t<c we put it at zero and move on to an improper integral of c to inf. This is where I get stuck.

@user312484   Then, consider the change of variable $x := t-c$.

@Abezhiko if I do that I would have to change the piecewise entirely correct?
c<t would become 0<x+c
And 0<t<c would become 0<x+c<0

@user312484  No, the definition $g$ remains the same, but it will shift the integral boundary. I'll write an answer in a few minutes.

Starting from the definition of the Laplace transform, you have to apply a translation (hence the title of the exercise, by the way) through the change of variable $x := t-c$, as done below :
$$
\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}[g](s) 
   &= \int_0^\infty g(t)e^{-st} \,\mathrm{d}t \\
   &= \int_\color{red}{c}^\infty f(t-c)e^{-st} \,\mathrm{d}t \\
   &= \int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-s(x+c)} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &= e^{-sc} \int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-sx} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &= e^{-sc}\mathscr{L}[f](s)
\end{align}
$$

This helped. Thank you!
